# pcolor in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am using pcolor in matplotlib. I use a three dimensional array as the input. I want to arrange the third array to be displayed in a log scale. Is there an option to do this? If I take a logarithm of the third array before plotting it, the sub one values become negative and pcolor no longer works.

Comment: Neither you nor matplotlib can take the logarithm of a negative number.  I assume you mean the sub-one values become negative, and pcolor doesn't work for those cases.  Consider an offset.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the data of your third dimension are all positive (since the log of a negative number is undefined), then you should not have any issues plotting this using `pcolor` (note: the Matplotlib documentation recommends `pcolormesh` rather than `pcolor`). At this point, I'll call attention to the post's edit history which shows that "sub one" used to say "subzero", which would produce `NaN`s; I will address this later. As the current version says, the logarithm of a number less than 1 (and greater than 0) is negative. You mention having an issue plotting negative numbers using `pcolor`, but that should not affect anything.

Assuming positive numbers, the code below should work.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.close("all")

N = 20
x = np.linspace(0, 1, N)
y = np.linspace(0, 1, N)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
Z = X**2 + Y + 0.1

data = np.stack((X, Y, Z), axis=0)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
p = ax.pcolor(data[0], data[1], np.log(data[2]))
fig.colorbar(p, ax=ax, label="ln(z)")
ax.set_xlabel("x")
ax.set_ylabel("y")
```

[image]

If we take instead consider the original text, using `np.log` for the negative numbers will produce `NaN`s, as mentioned earlier. Switching our `Z` definition to `Z = X**2 - Y + 0.1`, we will get a warning.

```py
RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in log
  p = ax.pcolor(data[0], data[1], np.log(data[2]))
```

This will still produce a plot, but the locations where the data are `NaN` will not be plotted.

[image]

Versions:

- Python: 3.10.9
- Matplotlib: 3.7.0
- NumPy: 1.23.5